# Any way to save a large float array as an Android resource file for future use?

Tags: android

I am writing an Android application that uses a large quantity of numeric information.

Right now I load the data in through a text file from the "/res/raw/" directory and then parse the text into a two dimensional float[][] array.

Is there any way to save this float[][] array as a resource file that can then be loaded by the program directly?

This would potentially save lots of time at start-up because the program would not have to parse lots of text, convert each element from text to float, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javarmi/chapter/ch10.html) has a pretty good overview of serialization.  You can use the ObjectOutputStream like:

```
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("test")));
```

Then you'd use the ObjectInputStream to read things back.  Serializing and de-serializing from a file will require you to come up with some mechanism for delineating the separate arrays for your first dimension.  You're other option would be to convert your two dimensional array into a Map of Lists.  The huge benefit there is that Collections are serializable, so writing and reading them from files is much easier.